# TO_DATE() with ISO date format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

Bellow code get error with `ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format`

```
SELECT to_date('23-04-2014', 'fxdd-mm-iyyy') FROM DUAL
```

please explain why i can't give date format as ISO year

Comment: are you sure about the `fxdd` ?

Comment: the `fx` is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: This is totally not ISO format though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means you have something wrong with your input format:

```
SQL> SELECT to_date('23-04-2014', 'fxdd-mm-iyyy') dd FROM DUAL;

ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format

SQL> SELECT to_date('23-04-2014', 'fxdd-mm-yyyy') dd FROM DUAL;

DD
-----------
23/04/2014
```

Have a look at the [datetime format elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212), the year format `iyyy` doesn't exist!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, TO_DATE doesn't support that, try this:

SELECT to_char(DATE '2014-04-23' , 'fxdd-mm-iyyy') FROM DUAL;

Hope this helps.